# The best way to have a Java Lambda case insensitive sort using sorted

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8

I'm looking at the Lambda sorted method and I can't seem to find a case insensitive attribute very easily. Here is the code.

```
@org.junit.Test
public void StackOverflowQuestion() throws Exception {

    List<String> sut = Arrays.asList("Xena","Scarlet","Joseph", "adam");
    Stream<String> output = sut.stream().sorted();

    output.forEach(trans2 -> System.out.println(trans2.toString()));

}
```

my output is
Joseph
Scarlet
Xena
adam

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [How hard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) did [you look](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)?

Comment: Besides that… what’s the point of calling `.toString()` on a `String()`?

Comment: I reused some code from a prior test case...

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, but what's the syntax to **do** it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
Stream<String> output = sut.stream().sorted(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sorted` method can optionally take in a `Comparator` as a way to compare two objects in your `Stream`.  In this case, your `Comparator` can compare the lowercase versions of your `String`s.